# How can I handle a promise in Jest?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, promise, jestjs

I'm getting an error right in this part of my code. `Received promise resolved instead of rejected` and I'm not sure how to handle this, can anyone help me?

```
it("should not create a media if the user doesn't exist", async () => {
    user.user= undefined;
    await usersRepository.save(user);

    await expect(
      createMedia.execute({
        userId: user.id,
        type: 'video',
        media: 'video-media',
        description: 'description',
      }),
    ).rejects.toBeInstanceOf(AppError);
  });
```

And:

```
expect(received).rejects.toThrow()

    Received promise resolved instead of rejected
    Resolved to value: {"description": "description", "id": "id number", "media": "video-media", "userId": "id user", "type": "video"}
```

Comment: What is this test supposed to do? It says that promise resolved successfully and not thrown error. From the jest perspective this test is correct. You should investigate why `createMedia.execute` didn't throw

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your test looks fine and it's failing because your SUT (system under test) has completed normally, while your test is expecting it to throw an error.

Comment: It's weird, this is only validating if the user tries to upload more media than they can. The test ends with "Error: Process completed with exit code 1".

Comment: @MartinDevillers Thanks and thank you for your time! :) Would there be any way to resolve this so that this error disappears?

Comment: Yes, first verify your SUT is actually throwing an error. You may also need to use `rejects.toThrow(AppError)` instead of `toBeInstanceOf`

Comment: I did what you mentioned about `rejects.toThrow(AppError)` and updated my question with the error description. I still don't know what to do...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is creating a successful promise, which you then test against a rejects, so it fails because it executes successfully and you're telling it that you expect it to fail.

When you use `.rejects` you're telling the `expect` that you expect it to fail and be rejected, in this case it's succeeding.  If you change that to a `resolves` instead of a `rejects`, it will work.

Or you have to make sure that the query you're doing will actually fail by i.e. updating something that doesn't exist.

Another way is to actually execute your query, get the result from it and then do an `expect` assertation on the return data.

For more clarity a normal promise looks like this:

```
const example = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => ...
```

Then you can call those resolve and reject methods depending on whether the promise resolved correctly or if it failed you can call the reject.  When you use `.resolves` or `.rejects` in jest it's testing those resolve and reject methods on the promise.

When you're using an `async` function you don't actually see that, but it's doing the same thing.

What's more is when users upload more files than they actually can, it will break, which is why in your case it actually doesn't fail, because then it actually does get rejected.

Comment: Thank you for your reply and for your time. Got it, but where can I put the resolve? Is there any way to put it in and keep the "reject" the way it is? Sorry if it sounds a bit silly, I'm still a beginner in this part of development

Comment: ````expect().rejects```` will test if the promise rejects, ````expect.resolves```` will test if it succeeded, in your case you can keep what you have but then you have to make sure you're doing a DB query that is actually failing/rejecting, in your case it's succeeding.  Or you have to make the DB call, get the result back, then use ````expect```` on the result without any rejects/resolves.

Comment: Small addition - don't forget to `await` the `expect().rejects` otherwise everything that comes after won't be run (in the context of the test). Also, if this assertion fails, it won't stop your test process.